# In how many ways can $7$ people be chosen out of $12$ people so that $2$ given people can never be selected together?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Is it right to take the combination of $7$ out of $12$ and subtract the combination of $5$ out of $10$ so i take out the ways that both of them are chosen?

So it will be $792-252=540$

I just find the number way too small.

Comment: Since you are only interested in those selections in which two given people can never be selected together, you should change your title to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have those $2$ given people then what we can do is choose $1$ out of that group of $2$ and then choose the rest out of the remaining $10$, and then also add the possibility that none of the 2 are in the group, so $${2 \choose 1}\cdot{10 \choose 6} +  {2 \choose 0}\cdot{10 \choose 7}= 540$$

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question but I only want them not to be together in the group that we pick, not on the remaining one.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not quite right, but you can use your idea.

You have $\binom{12}{7}$, which are all combinations of $7$ out of $12$ people, disregarding that person $A$ and $B$ must not be together.

You want to leave out the choices, where $A$ and $B$ are together, so you assume you choose both $A$ and $B$, leaving $5$ choices among $10$, which is why you subtract $\binom{10}{5}$.

But you forgot that you could also *not* have chosen *both* $A$ and $B$, so that both of these people end up in the group that wasn't chosen. But if you fix $A$ and $B$ in the group that was not chosen, then you are left with choosing $7$ people out of $10$, i.e. $\binom{10}{7}$.

In total, you get $\binom{12}{7}-\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{7} = 420.$

*Edit*: As per the comments, the answer to the intended question is $\binom{12}{7}-\binom{10}{5}$, as in the original post.

Comment: I think C(2,1) is fair enough in place of your C(10,5)+C(10,7).

Comment: @mathlover Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How could I replace C(10,5)+C(10,7) by C(2,1)?

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question but I only want them not to be together in the group that we pick, not on the remaining one.

Comment: @user300822 Then you are correct.

Comment: The extension of this idea is the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: I found this question on quora too but Tim Farage has a different approach with a different result though.Could he be right? Here is the link:
https://www.quora.com/In-how-many-ways-can-k-people-be-chosen-out-of-n-people-so-that-2-given-people-can-never-be-together